# How to cross compile Qt with gstreamer

Tags: qt, arm, cross-compiling, qtmultimedia

I want cross compiled qt5.12.3 with gstreamer for my arm board,
I have cross compiled gstreamer-1.0 and gst-plugin-base-1.0 ,set their path correctly,but one error comes when configure,like this

```
ERROR: Feature 'gstreamer' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'features.gstreamer_1_0 || features.gstreamer_0_10' failed.
```

can anybody tell me how to fix it?